# Facebook old website og:image cahced

Tags: facebook, caching, metadata

I redesigned my website recently and one of the changes was using `index.php` instead of `index.html` and changing one of the `og:image` metadata property from `favicon_1.jpg` to `favicon.jpg`.

Now, facebook still shows the old `og:image`, even after I used the url linter.

This is what the ["scraper sees"](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fiulianonofrei.com):

> `<meta property="og:image" content="http://iulianonofrei.com/images/favicon.jpg">
>
>   <meta property="og:image" content="http://iulianonofrei.com/images/macro/splinter.jpg">`

And this is the [graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/10150209588122211):

> `"image": [
>
>         {
>
>            "url": "http://iulianonofrei.com/images/favicon_1.jpg"
>
>         },
>
>         {
>
>            "url": "http://iulianonofrei.com/images/macro/grass_2_t.jpg"
>
>         }`

How can I update the links to show the current ones? Also, the second one is generated by php so I want it to update recordingly, or at least to update properly when I run it through the linter.

And also I have a [warning](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=iulianonofrei.com) which I can't figure it out and it annoys me!

Comment: Are you sure you're not checking two different URLs? you said above you changed the URL from .html to .php, this is a different URL

Comment: It should pick it all alone since it's the only `index` file, and also, `.../index.php` retrieves the exact same data

Comment: No, the exact URL that you're sharing is the one you should be checking - if it redirects elsewhere facebook's crawler will follow the redirect - check [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) for the URL you're sharing/liking/posting and see if the tags detected there are correct

Comment: same thing, still not working

Comment: what's the URL? Are you SURE [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) is showing one image but another is appearing when you share the EXACT same URL?

Comment: `http://iulianonofrei.com` is the exact url and yes, I am very sure

Comment: That URL doesn't load for me from two different servers

Comment: what do you mean? what servers? what `og:image` links do you get in the `Object Properties` category?

Comment: Nothing, your site just isn't accessible for me from here in the US or from a server in Europe:
`curl http://iulianonofrei.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
`

Comment: Neither does [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=iulianonofrei.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. I needed to change the `og:url` from `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/index.php`.